# Can EditTextCell's text be reset in a CellTable?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm working with GWT-2.1.0 and I've draw a table through *CellTable* which contains a column, the third, of *EditTextCell*. I'm trying to modify the value of that cell for each visible rows by code using:

```
table.getRowElement(i).getCells().getItem(2).setInnerHTML("<div style=\"outline:none;\" tabindex=\"-1\">0</div>");
Window.alert("Pause");
```

Thanks the alert I can see that all the rows have been updated correctly to the new value, but, once the cycle ends, a refresh of the table restore the user's input nullify the job done.

Is there some temporary cache that EditTextCell uses to mantain the data? Can I erase the text inserted by the user in another way? Can I reach the Column of the CellTable so allowing me to use the *setValue(...)* field?

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Using **.setInnerText("0");* fails too. 
P.P.S  I've read that GWT2.2.0 should have a *CellTable.getColumn(int index)* method to do so, but I don't know if it's useful to me - and, more important, when it should comes out.

Answer (score 0):

EditTextCell is a subclass of [AbstractEditableCell](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.1/gwt-dev-2.1.1-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.html#clearViewData%28java.lang.Object%29), which has the clearViewData method. You can call that method for all objects in the table for which you want the data to be cleared.